# Jquery/ajax Image slider - finding source

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need to have this effect on my php website. [There are 3 images in the image i have linked](http://cdn1.1stwebdesigner.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/jQueryGlobe-jQuery-Plugin.png) with, and it changes every 2 seconds. Does anyone knows if there's any source code available in order to get this effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically i'm using this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/raymondralibi/mbjzC/) for this [website](http://starqle.com)